# An alternative to the Gaussian distribution to describe/fit market stock returns

Tags: equities, normal-distribution

After the financial crisis in 2008, many people (including me) don't really believe that stock returns can be described in terms of the normal distribution (Gaussian distribution).

But besides the Gaussian distribution, is there any other distribution that was found to be a better way of describing how the stock market behaves?

Comment: You could try [a Levy skew alpha-stable distribution with α = 1.8 and β = 0.931](http://epicureandealmaker.blogspot.co.at/2012_06_01_archive.html). Snark aside, it depends on your use-case , asset, etc.

Comment: @Gravitron [Cont 2000](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~rama/papers/empirical.pdf)

Comment: another nice paper :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think one has to distinguish between pricing and fitting/reproducing empirical stock returns. A model might fit the empirical stock returns extremly well but fail to reproduce derivative prices.  In my answer I will assume that you are interested in reproducing the empirical stock returns.

**Mandelbrot and the Stable Paretian Hypothesis**

The most salient difference between the Normal distribution and the real world data are the **heavy tails**. 
This has been first noted (or at least publicly asserted) by [Bernoit Mandelbrot](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beno%C3%AEt_Mandelbrot) and resulted in his **[Stable Paretian Hypothesis](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/341/handouts/Fama_MandelbroitAndStableParetianHypothesis.pdf)**. Mandelbrot argued that contrary to the Gaussian-Haypothesis the variance of stock returns can be infinite resulting in heavy tails. He proposes the use of  [stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) with infinite variance - that also known as **stable paretian distributions**. (for more on the stable paretian distributions see once again the paper on elaborating on the [Stable Paretian Hypothesis](http://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/341/handouts/Fama_MandelbroitAndStableParetianHypothesis.pdf))

Thus most contemporary approaches focuse on designing distributions (or processes with transition densities) that feature heavy tails.

---

**Concrete suggestions**

First of all I don't think "the one" distribution for stock returns actually exists. Heavy-Tail ones will in most cases outperform the Normal distribution. The concrete choice may depend on the data one is working with. Still, there is a couple of examples worth mentioning.

The **Heston-Model** does a decent job in capturing the high kurtosis and the fat tails of stock returns. The paper [Goodness-of-fit of the Heston model](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0305055v1.pdf) provides a detailes analysis. As it turns out the Heston-Model is well suited for reproducing daily and up to monthly returns but doesn't perform as well with annual stock returns. The original paper on the transition density of the HM can be [found here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0203046.pdf). The authors also have their own paper discussing how well the Heston-Model performs with respect to empirical stock returns ([Comparison between the probability distribution
of returns in the Heston model and empirical
data for stock indexes](http://physics.umd.edu/~yakovenk/papers/PhysicaA-324-303-2003.pdf))

I can also wholeheartedly recommend the paper on [the Goodness-of-fit of the Heston, **Variance-Gamma** and
**Normal-Inverse Gaussian Models**](http://www.econ.boun.edu.tr/content/wp/EC2013_16.pdf)
It is very extensive, comprehensive and simultaneously provides a good introduction to the respective models

Due to it's fat tails the **[student-t distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)** also performes reasonably well at reproducing market stock returns. *As Aksakal has already mentioned in the comments below Student t is not a stable distribution.* Still, there are some references using it to fit stock returns and even to construct a random walk. For a reference on the prior confer the paper by Eckhard Platen on [Empirical Evidence
on Student-tLog-Returns of Diversied World Stock Indices](http://www.qfrc.uts.edu.au/research/research_papers/rp194). A construction of student t random walk can be found in [A Benchmark Approach to Quantitative Finance](http://books.google.de/books?id=ZABv5sBn7Y4C&pg=PA476&lpg=PA476&dq=student%20t%20transition%20density&source=bl&ots=rGrXoZGRiy&sig=Sc0Jb0BbDCU9Pkugel8u9OC2iuk&hl=de&sa=X&ei=_lYXU_OcI4eN4gSduYD4Aw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=student&f=false) by Platen and Heath.

---

**How to go from transition density to the distribution of returns**

My explanation above did not calrify how knowing the transition density of a process also gives information on the distribution/density of the returns.

Assume a process $\ln(X_t)$ has the transition density $p(s,x,t,y)$. $p(s,x,t,y)$ can be interpreted as the probability of the process to move from $X_s=x$ at time $s$ to $X_t=y$ at time $t$. Thus if we set $s=0, x=0$ and $t=\Delta t$ (e.g. one day, one weel etc) we arrive at a density $p(0,0,\Delta t,y)$. This function describes the probability of the process to increass by $y$ within a time step of $\Delta t$. Thus depending on choice of $\Delta t$ wone is able to retrieve the theoretical. distribution of daily, montly, etc. returns.

Comment: Nice references! Why are you not even mentioning Student t? Are there any major drawbacks? Do you know of comparisons with NIG and VG?

Comment: @Quarts thanks for bringig up student t. I decided to stick to densitites/distributions that result from relevant processes that can be used to model stock returns. Still, there are some cases when the student-t happens to be the stationary density of such a process - I will edit the post accordingly :)

Comment: Student t isn't stable.

Comment: any reference ? Also I think there isn't just the one distribution. It depends on the market and the data ;) Still for almost all cases (above all in daily returns) normal distribution has been refuted

Comment: @Aksakal and why would that be a disadvantage? On the countrary, empirical distributions are well known to be far from stable, that's why one has to resort at least to hacks like tempered stable distributions.

Comment: I still added a paragraph on stable non gaussian distribution and why they apply etc. :)

Comment: @Quartz, one issue is that random walk is defined as $x_t-x_{t-\Delta t}=\varepsilon_t$, so if you change the interval $\Delta t$ non-stable distributions change too. e.g. for some reason you decided to use Student t for monthly returns, now annual returns or weekly or daily are not Student t anymore. what is the theory here? why suddenly a monthly is Student t and all others are not? how dailies combine into monthly this way? when you think of this it becomes clear that you picked Student t simply because it's fat tailed

Comment: @Quartz, another issue is this. we're talking about stock returns. what about prices? when you use Student t the expectation of a price is not defined. it's not the end of the world, but you better be prepared to deal with this.

Comment: @Aksakal is the rest of the comment directed at me? I tried to provide some references. Also student t isn't my personal first choice but there are some works showing that it performs quite OK

Comment: @Aksakal it is nice that you are mentioning prices/pricing. I primarily focused on the stock returns. As mentioned at the beginning pricing models must not necessarily replicate the distribution of log returns. I also added your comment on the non-stability of the student t distribution - thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @Probilitator, it's a general comment. I used Student t myself, and was able defend its usage, but learned a lot about its problems in the mean time. by price issue I mean this: $E[aset price]=E[\exp(r)]=\infty$ when $r$ is the Student t return. as I wrote it's not the end of the world, but be ready to answer questions

Comment: @Aksakal why not post it as a question/answer on quant SE. I don't think that such knowledge is easily accessible. Most texts only introduce the student-t and don't really explain it't pittfalls :)

Comment: @Aksakal we all know Student t is not a perfect distribution, I was just pointing out that alpha stable ones have even more problems. And again, the fact that aggregating t returns thins down the tails is wanted, due to empirical observations, while stable ones do remain in the family but at the high cost of tail persistence. Why sacrifice accuracy of approximation for mathematical "elegance"? Moreover afaik that issue with price expectation is even more pronounced with stable distributions, please correct me.

Comment: @Quartz, normal is a stable distribution, so not all stable distributions have the issue with the undefined mean price. The Student t's problem with aggregation is that it's not clear how daily distributions summed up to monthly Student t. In my opinion Student t is not the way to deal with fat tails in RW. Stochastic vol approach makes more sense to me, it's theoretically more elegant too

Comment: @Aksakal: yes, SV is certainly better, also as a fit to data, but can be unpractical for certain tasks. Anyway one can circumvent the Student t aggregation "problem" quite easily in practice. PS: for most dof-s Student t log-returns shall also have finite mean, or not?

Comment: Log returns have mean. Exp of these returns doesn't.

Comment: @Aksakal: [Student t pricing](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4092).

Comment: @Quartz, i know this paper. it's truncated Student t, i.e. they clip out the tails :)

Comment: @Aksakal: right, I should have checked first... what a silly cheat!

Comment: @Quartz, it's not silly if you do it right. there is another paper where the authors looked at how much to clip out from the tail to preserve their fatness, while taking care of the explosion in in the integrals. i think [this](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperInformation.aspx?paperID=25549#.UzLqqPldV8E) is the paper

Comment: @Aksakal: I don't get it: if the integral explodes you can clip arbitrarily and get any desired pseudoresult, or not? What's the meaning and use? Unless of course the boundary is fixed ex ante. Anyway I'm still not convinced, need to work out that integral: t-s approximate a normal arbitrarily. Thanks for the link!

Comment: your distribution will have larger kurt than normal, but it will have a limited domain. so in that regard you still have fatter tails. it's not unreasonable to limit the domain, e.g. your stock price can not be $\infty$, it cant be larger than all the money out there, i.e. there's some kind of limit on it.

Comment: Of course S can be larger than all the money out there: we live in a fractional reserve system. :) Anyway that would be an ex ante fixed boundary, so that one is not really solving that integral but a variant; it's not the same as having freedom of truncation.

Answer (score 7):

My take on the whole issue is as follows: We cannot be sure to find *the one and only true model*, the only thing we can do is to identify the most prevalent so called stylized facts and try to model them parsimoniously. The following paper was already mentioned in the comments:

[Empirical properties of asset returns: stylized facts and statistical issues by Rama Cont (2000)](http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~rama/papers/empirical.pdf)

One route to go is to use more complicated yet better fitting distributions, the other route (the one I prefer and actively do research on) is to use mixtures of simpler distributions (e.g. normal distributions again). Most of the stylized facts mentioned in the abovementioned paper (p. 224) can be modeled by a simple mixture of normals. As a starting point I would recommend the following excellent paper:

[Regime Changes and Financial Markets by Andrew Ang and Allan G. Timmermann (2011)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1919497)

From the abstract:

> [...] In empirical estimates, the regime switching means, volatilities,
>   autocorrelations, and cross-covariances of asset returns often differ
>   across regimes, which allow regime switching models to capture the
>   stylized behavior of many financial series including fat tails,
>   heteroskedasticity, skewness, and time-varying correlations. [...]

Have e.g. a look at figure 1 (p. 27): There you see how a mixture of just two normals can very well and parsimoniously model fat tails.

Comment: I forgot about gaussian mixture models :) they are quite en vouge nowadays - +1